# Grothendieck-Messing in characteristic 0?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, deformation-theory

Let $A$ is an abelian scheme over a base scheme $S$. Let $S \rightarrow S'$ be a thickening defined by an ideal of square zero (for example).

If $p$ is locally nilpotent on $S$, then Serre-Tate and Grothendieck-Messing imply that lifting $A$ to $S'$ is "the same" as lifting the Hodge filtration on the Dieudonné crystal (evaluated on $S$) of the associated $p$-divisible group.

Is there anything similar if the base scheme $S$ is characteristic zero? Mixed characteristic? Say, using the Hodge filtration on algebraic de Rham cohomology?

Comment: I think one needs to use not just algebraic de Rham cohomology but its isomorphism with singular cohomology for this.

Comment: You can make this work with crystalline cohomology of abelian schemes in char 0. Essentially you just have to show that the Kodaira-Spencer map is the same as whet you get from the hodge filtration thing. It is easier than the char p case (especially if you first prove the thing for p-divisible groups which is quite a bit harder as you have to prove unobstructedness first).

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments. @Johan Do you know whether this is written down somewhere?